# Highstock - click drag on the portion of the graph to zoom?

Tags: highcharts

In Highstock you have the navigator at the bottom which lets you zoom in and out of the chart.

But, is it also possible to click on the chart itself, drag to highlight a certain portion of the chart and zoom into that area?

I've seen this feature in some of the other charting tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `chart.zoomType`, see: http://jsfiddle.net/MKeWv/ - [docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#chart.zoomType).

Comment: Thanks so much for answering ALLLLLL of my questions in the last few days... seriously. No wonder I pay for Highchart. :) You have a seriously happy customer here.